# Mock method of an instance variable of an angular service in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In essence I want to create a spy object of something of the like:

myService.myVariable.get()

However, I can't seem to mock it properly. If i try

```
 myServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj("myService", ["myVariable"]);
```

Then I get that .get() is undefined for it. Similarly

```
 myServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj("myService", ["myVariable.get"]);
```

Then I get that myVariable is undefined in the test. In case it is relevant, the code to inject our mock service:

```
vm = $componentController('home', {$uibModal: modal, myService: myService});
```

I'm not looking at all to test the service, I just want to be able to intercept that call. In the component being tested, the line calling this is

```
myService.myService.get({.....});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging, I ended up doing the following:

```
myService = jasmine.CreateSpyObj("myService", ["myVariable"]);
myService.myVariable.get = function() {}
```

And then later when I wanted to change my spy to call a fake function:

```
spyOn(myService.myVariable, "get").and.callFake(function(){...});
```

--Note: I believe that the second and third lines can be concatenated into one if you don't want the function to change, using the 'createSpy' function. However, I didn't take this route

Comment: I would go a step further and do: myService.myVariable.get = jasmine.createSpy(),
and now you have a proper spy in place of your get function.